# Cost of HAVING but NOT throwing an exception in a method in .NET

Tags: .net, performance, exception

This question is not about the cost of throwing exceptions in .NET. In some experiments a while back I saw a significant change in a method performance if it *contained* a throw statement somewhere in one of the execution paths, without actually ever using it. Does JIT somehow wraps any method that potentially could throw an exception in some extra code?

Comment: The overhead is only substantial when exceptions are actually thrown. I suggest you retest.

Comment: It shouldn't, but this is fairly testable - write a test snippet of code that calls 2 methods, one with a throw and one without, and look at the IL generated.

Comment: A quick test shows no significant difference, as long as the exception is not thrown

Comment: do you still have the code for your experiments? Maybe you've hit some strange corner-case where (for instance) the presence of the  throw does not let the compiler optimize a certain piece of code

Comment: Possibly the additional time was consumed by the condition used to test whether the exception should be thrown rather than the mere presence of the throw. If you time it, make sure both versions execute the conditional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.  The x86 and x64 jitter optimizers will never inline a method that has a *throw* statement.  The difference is hard to quantify because additional optimizations are possible after it got inlined, but typically a couple of nanoseconds per call.

An optimization strategy used commonly in the .NET framework code is to put the statements that throw the exception in a helper method so that the common code path is still inlined.  Visible in the Math.Abs() method for example:

```
public static int Abs(int value)
{
    if (value >= 0) return value;
    return AbsHelper(value);
}

private static int AbsHelper(int value)
{
    if (value == int.MaxValue) throw new OverflowException(...);
    return -value;
}
```

Which ensures that the Abs() method itself is inlined and only negative values take the non-optimal code path.